# Is Xcode 4 preview 2 stable enough to be used for development?

Tags: xcode4

Is Xcode 4 preview 2 stable enough to be used for development?

Since the final version is out, this thread can be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen recently, it's quite unstable. It was hard to use it for more than a couple of minutes before it crashed. I certainly would not use it on a real project.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate a crash 2-3 times a day. Some features like the Version control, and the use of the assistance view seem especially buggy. I really love it, but i find it hard to work with in it's current form

Answer (score 1):

I find it really unstable. I hoped that i could use it but had to move back to xcode 3. I had several hard bugs in interface builder, wich meant it was unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your needs.

If you need to pump out programs for the App Store as fast as possible, then Xcode 3.2 is still your most efficient use of time.

If you would gain a lot from the new features like the static analyser and SCM updates (git is integrated, for example) and you can afford to go a little slower (crashes, learning the new design and layout) then Xcode 4 is excellent.

I am spending time learning Xcode 4 because I'm excited about the new tools and don't have massive time/money pressures. I see it as an investment in my overall developer skills.

It's stable enough for development, but not for production environments just yet: My own personal projects are being done in Xcode 4, but at work we use Xcode 3.2 for developing iPhone apps for clients.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded it, and didn't have any problems before I tried to make an archive. My project includes RestKit library, and xCode has some particular problem with linking of static libraries. This is BIG issue, as you can't publish your app on store, or ad-hoc.