# Xcode 4 - ready for production use? Also, console window behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode4

(Currently using Xcode 3.2, hesitant to move to a newer version until it's stable and practical, but am about to start on new projects.)

Q. Is the Xcode 4 preview suitable for production work (i.e. releasing Mac/iOS apps), or should I wait until a final build is released?

Q1. I've watched Apple's State of Tools WWDC video, where they talk at length about the one-window approach to Xcode.   I live and die by my console window.  Is that window also integrated in to the IDE window, or can I have the console window appear separately?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to point out that you can use the normal "Console" application to see output of your NSLog() messages, even if they run on the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> Q. Is the Xcode 4 preview suitable for
>   production work (i.e. releasing
>   Mac/iOS apps), or should I wait until
>   a final build is released?

You can develop in Xcode 4, and move back and forth between Xcode 4 and 3 with the same projects. You are *meant* to use Xcode 3.2 for submissions to the App Store, but it isn't clear whether that is enforced or just that bugs in Xcode 4 could get your app rejected.

Mac apps don't go through the app store, so if it builds and deploys, away you go :) Make sure to test thoroughly on your deployment platform(s) just in case!

> I live and die by my console window.
>   Is that window also integrated in to
>   the IDE window, or can I have the
>   console window appear separately?

It's integrated. You can go to the debugger navigator or you can 'show debugger area' from the view menu to have it appear below the other navigator areas

I can't post images, but you can see them at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A75R.png and i.imgur.com/hAjqx.png

On the overall questions of stability/practicality: My experience is that the new design is really nice. Things are laid out much more logically. It still slows down the process of coding as you adapt, but I'm digging the new Xcode and think I'll be faster with it overall.

There are bugs, especially if you push the envelope. Using LLDB instead of GDB tends to cause my computer to lock up entirely, for example :(

If you need to be productive and you want to waste the least amount of time getting things into the App Store right now, Xcode 3.2 is where you should be.

If you want to muck around and can afford to spend time learning the new design and features while dealing with crashes, then Xcode 4 is very rewarding. Long-term, it is a big improvement on the current Xcode.

Comment: Thank you to both Luke and Zem for your help.

Answer (score 13):

To detach the console as a separate window: (in a DIY manner)

1. Open a new window (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Hide the left bar and the utilities bar if open (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)
3. Open the Debug area (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>)
4. Drag the Debug area until it covers the whole window, then hide the toolbar.

There, you have a window you can resize or drag anywhere, that shows only the console output. Just like the good old times.

Comment: Thank you... I use 4 monitors and I thought this update was going to ruin my system.

Comment: Fantastic! Always nice to find ways to re-enable my productivity! :)

Comment: Thx for the tip but can not resize the new window too much (Xcode 14). On a 13" MacBook Pro, the new window's width can be reduced to only about 75% of the width of the screen. Maybe this is OK if you a large, say 27" monitor, but not on the 13" MBP.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, its ok for HelloWorld projects but I dont think Apple have dont anything like the required usability and documentation testing.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can install the Xcode 4 preview without replacing your existing version of Xcode; in fact, it will install like this by default. So you don't lose anything by trying it out.

From my experience, the preview builds perfectly functional apps, but I run into issues often enough with missing features (either they've moved where I can't find them, or they just aren't implemented yet) and occasional crashes that I've gone back to 3.2 for my actual work. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379490/is-xcode-4-preview-2-stable-enough-to-be-used-for-development) reveal similar reactions from others.

I checked just now and I couldn't find a way to detach the console or anything else into a separate window, but I didn't try very hard.

Answer (score 0):

xcode 4 preview 6 pretty much sucks in terms of performance. the direction is great with lots and lots of useful features, from the interface to the debugger and instruments. however, it crashes often or the process hangs. for constant and flowing development i advise you use xcode 3x. check out xcode 4 and enjoy the new features heading our way.

Comment: Thanks pengas. I'm still waiting off until it goes final. Life is too short, Mac/iOS app delivery is already too tricky. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched to XCODE 4 this week and I simply love it.  Sure, it crashes occasionally (well, it crashes EVERYTIME at startup, but lets you continue).

All the windows are there and you have multitude of options on how to lay them out.

The most impressive feature to me is how it now deals with compiler errors.  I use VIM to edit my code - as soon as I write the file out, XCODE compiles it and shows me any errors (I don't need to 'build').  Even nicer is the fact that now it also has a button to go from error to error instead of having to painfully scroll up to the red lines.

And crashes in my app are simply WONDERFUL now.  At any crash, the exact line of C code that crashed is displayed and all the local variables at that point in time are displayed.  Brilliant!

Yes, it is a bit buggy and crashes or hangs from time to time.  But seriously, after just a couple of days on it I really don't want to go back.