# XCode 4 output console on the right of code editor area?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

How do i move debugger/output console from bottom to the right of editor area?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 - detach the console/log window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306276/xcode-4-detach-the-console-log-window)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can do that, but you can alternatively run the console in a [new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697551/xcode-4-ready-for-production-use-also-console-window-behaviour/5270933#5270933), which you can resize and place wherever you want.

Comment: Thx for the tip but can not resize the new window too much (Xcode 14). On a 13" MacBook Pro, the new window's width can be reduced to only about 75% of the width of the screen. Maybe this is OK if you a large, say 27" monitor, but not on the 13" MBP.