# How to show Xcode debugger in a window separate from Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode4

I was watching a video lecture from iTunes U., where instructor showed how one can take a debugger section of the Xcode and was able to pull that window away from the main.

Unfortunately, video showed instructions on how to do it in Xcode3. How might one do it in Xcode4?

How can one either detach a debugger section or, possibly, configure preferences to do it automatically?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Open a new tab, show the debugger (cmd-shift-Y) and drag the divider all the way to the top. Close the navigator (cmd-0) and inspector windows (cmd-opt-0), then drag the tab off into a new window.

If you [name the tab](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-tab_bar/Tab%20Bar/tab_bar.html) before you tear it off, e.g., "Debugger", then set up a Behavior in Xcode's preferences ( Preferences -> Behaviors -> Run Starts -> Show Tab "Debugger" ), it'll show that window when you run your app. It'll even recreate it if you close it.

If you have access to the WWDC 2011 videos, "Maximizing Productivity in Xcode 4" has a lot of great info.

Here's a screenshot before tearing the tab off:
[image]

Comment: This is nice, but this is not a separate window, in a sense that i can't move it, say, to another screen. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You'll have to tear the tab off, just like in Safari. If you want just an bare editor window, you can hide the toolbar on the new widow, (View -> Hide Toolbar) . The Behaviors feature I mentioned will restore that state for you, too.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, Debugger does not show up in a "tab". Can you please post a screenshot of a debugger before tearing it off?

Comment: (cmd-T) to create a new tab. Double-click in the tab title to change the name of the tab.

Comment: Working in XCode 10 too. To rename the tab go to the Window menu (not the most intuitive - why cant you option click the tab name?)

Answer (score 51):

I know it's a little too late, but I'm going to be borrowing [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5306656/361247). Go to your preferences, go to the behaviour tab. Change the running behaviour to show a new window.

If you don't want the window to have an editor or toolbar, you can customise it that way too.

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks! Had no idea how much one can customise the behaviour of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks! Also pay attention to the `Pauses` options as well. That defines what happens when a breakpoint is hit (which may be closer to most of the people are looking for).

Comment: What's the purpose of doing this?

Comment: It's good for when you're using your laptop and want to debug on a separate dedicated window. @Honey

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 11

Change behaviour

```
Xcode -> Preferences... -> Behaviors -> Running -> Starts -> Show tab named <tab_name> in active window
```

[image]

After that <tab_name> tab will be opened automatically

To create a new tab manually:

1. Create a new tab

```
File -> New -> Tab
```

2. Rename  the  tab

```
Window -> Rename Tab... -> <tab_name>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding "Rename the tab" which is a dead link in the accepted answer.