# Show debugger on Xcode launch

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

Is there a way to launch Xcode debugger as soon as Xcode is launched, in a separate window (not tab)? I am using two monitors and I want to show debugger on a new window.

I know you can double click on a class and show debugger and hide all the rest to make it a full size window showing only the debugger but I want this to trigger automatically.

I know its something to do with **Xcode -> Preferences -> Behaviours ->**

Comment: Don't you need to run (`Cmd-R`) before the debugger has something to debug?

Comment: I want to have the window of the debugger for me to use it as soon as I run something.

Comment: Used the method of Droppy. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this very helpful question posted a few years back. Please navigate here for the solution

[How to show Xcode debugger in a window separate from Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115283/how-to-show-xcode-debugger-in-a-window-separate-from-xcode)

Comment: So you question is a dupe; please delete it.

Comment: that's a good idea i will