# Xcode 6 to Xcode 11 - Detach the Console/Log Window

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to detach the console/log window in Xcode 6 to Xcode 9? If so, how do you detach it from the main console, into it's own window?

This question was previously asked for Xcode 4 but the answer doesn't work for Xcode 6 to Xcode 9 -

- [Stackoverflow - Same Question for Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306276/xcode-4-detach-the-console-log-window)

See the attached screenshot for illustration of the console/log view in question

[image]

Comment: Apple took that away from us years ago! Apple knows best. If you want window flexibility "You are doing it wrong."

Comment: I found that I could maneuver and detach the console. 1. Add new tab. 2. Name the tab (eg Debugger). In the new tab, expand the console so it fills the main window. 4. Right-click the new tab and select open in new window. You'll have to quit Xcode and restart it to maintain the new window, rather than close projects or windows separately.

Comment: I can write this as an answer if it works for you.

Comment: this works David, thank you!!! Please write up the answer (I'll delete my posted picture after :)   )

Comment: In addition to @DavidDelMonte's awsome solution: Xcode still keeps popping up the console in the main window when the first output appears. To avoid that, go to `Xcode / Preferences / Behaviors / Running / Generates output`. Remove a checkmark from "show debugger with current views" and add a "Show tab names <your tab name here> in separate window". Now you can even close that window, it will open automatically.

Comment: P.S. works in Xcode 8.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, better late than never....

I found that I could maneuver and detach the console.

1. Add new tab.
2. Name the tab (eg Debugger).

In the new tab, expand the console so it fills the main window.

4. Right-click the new tab and select open in new window.

You'll have to quit Xcode and restart it to maintain the new window, rather than close projects or windows separately.

Apologize for the delay. Hope this is still useful..

UPDATE

1. This still works with Xcode 11.3!
2. To stop seperating the window : Xcode > Behaviors > Edit Behaviors

Then set as in the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

**Solution without restarting Xcode. Thank @David DelMonte for illuminating me.**

You can change Xcode behaviors configuration to open a new tab named Debugger in a separate window when project start running.

[image]

Then expand console view to full window in the debugger tab, Xcode will remember your reforms.

Comment: No longer possible with Xcode 14.

Comment: It is possible in Xcode 14 (tested with 14.2). Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/eNMp2VE

Answer (score 2):

This solution has worked for me in Xcode 14.2:

Under Behaviour > Running > Starts, change the following settings as in the screenshot below.

- Show window with name 'Debugger'
- Hide Navigator
- Show debugger with Console view
- Hide toolbar
- Hide current editor

[Xcode Behaviour Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWBX5.png)

This essentially just opens a new Xcode window and then hides everything except the console output. Hope this helps!

Comment: Any ideas for splitting consoles for two different builds running on two different device?